# Trouble creating a document with a connection to a related document in another collection using realm

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm, relationship

I have a person that has a related collection of “tags”. Each person can have multiple tags.

I’ve found the relationship CRUD section of the docs, but it skips the part that says how to actually write the code to connect two documents.

Here is a simplified version of my People schema.

```
export class People extends Realm.Object<People> {
  _id!: string;
  name: string;
  email?: string;
  tags?: Realm.List<Tags>;
  org_id!: string;

  static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    primaryKey: '_id',
    name: 'people',
    properties: {
      _id: {
        type: 'string',
        default: () => new Realm.BSON.ObjectID().toHexString(),
      },
      name: 'string',
      email: 'string?',
      createdAt: { type: 'date', default: () => new Date() },
      tags: 'tags[]',
      org_id: 'string',
    },
  };
}
```

And here is my Tags model

```
export class Tags extends Realm.Object<Tags> {
  _id!: string;
  name: string;
  org_id: string;

  static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    primaryKey: '_id',
    name: 'tags',
    properties: {
      _id: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      name: 'string',
      is_active: { type: 'bool', default: true },
      org_id: 'string',
    },
  };
}
```

Here is my code for adding a new person with one tag.

```
const person = realm.write(() => {
        return new People(realm, {
          email,
          name,
          org_id: org._id,
          tags: [{ _id: `${org._id}-2021` }],
        });
      });
```

I get the error `"Exception in HostFunction: Attempting to create an object of type ‘tags’ with an existing primary key value ‘‘id123-2021’’`

This is happening because realm is trying to create this same tag that already exists in the DB. Instead of creating it I need to connect the two. How do I do that?

Comment: Please see the Realm documentation to covers both one-to-one relationships as well as one-to-many [Realm Relationships](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/). Use that guide first - refer to the CRUD guide for more detailed info.

Comment: @Jay I have already reviewed the docs thoroughly. They don’t contain any code examples.

Comment: You may want to check again as there is a pretty good code example at the link in my prior comment. For example the line that shows `posts: 'Post[]',` is how to "connect" multiple posts documents to a single user. There are also code example of how to create inverse relationships through linkingObjects. If there is confusion about what Post[] property is, *where the type is a list or array of the related Realm object type*

Comment: @Jay This is all about types and not about implementation of the code itself to add or update linked objects. The example you reference is about how to find a linked object, not how to actually link one. I did find a solution though, so I'm going to post that as an answer.

Comment: The link in the above shows how to *structure* your object (not find) to have a relationship with another object through a `List` property. Then, if you look up the `List` property, there's a Push function which then adds additional objects to that list - that's what creates the relationship. It's pretty straightforward once you start working with it.

Comment: That push function is there because this is just a javascript array, which has many different built-in methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid constructors when you have a list of Realm objects.

```
realm.write(() => {
  const tmpId = `org-${_id}-2021`;
  let tag = realm.objectForPrimaryKey<Tag>(Tag, tmpId);
  if (!tag) {
    tag = new Tag(realm, { name: '2021', _id: tmpId });
  }  
  return people = new People(realm, {
    email,
    name,
    org_id: org._id,
    tags: [tag]
  });
});
```

The above code will check if `tag` has already been created by looking it up by primary key. If it hasn't, it will create it.

Answer (score 0):

Realm objects can be mutated inside the realm.write function directly. So in this case the way I was able to connect tags with people is like this.

```
    const person = realm.write(() => {
        const realmPerson = new People(realm, {
          email,
          name,
          org_id: org._id,
        });
        
        person.tags = [{ _id: `${org._id}-2021` }];
        return realmPerson;
    });
```

And since the _id is the primary key field Realm just knows these objects are linked and now if I later call person.tags, I actually get the whole array of tags with all the object properties, not just the _id field.

Comment: Not sure how this is any different from what I'm doing. In both cases an array of objects are being added. In simple example above I just have one object, but in reality I normally have more, so I use a map to loop over and assign that mapped array to person.tags.

Comment: Understood. What I was attempting to point out that this `{ _id: ${org._id}-2021 }` does not tie a tag back to the person. the `_id` is just a string that has no impact on that relationship. The relationship is in place because the tag was added to persons `tags` list, not because of `_id`. e.g. the tag `_id` could be `_id: "Hello, World"` and the relationship would still exist. So this would be more accurate *because the tag was added to the persons `tags` list property they have a one to many relationship*

Comment: @Jay I see, yes, good point, the relationship is there because of the schema.